# Using shapely.affinity and affine_transform?

Tags: python, shapely, affine-transformation

I have shapely.geometry Point:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
point1 = Point(0, 100, 200)
```

and I want to swap coordinates Y and Z:

```
from shapely.affinity import affine_transform
matrix = [1,0,0, 0,0,1, 0,1,0, 0,0,0]
point2 = affine_transform(point1, matrix)
```

I expect point2 will be POINT Z (0 200 100), but I have POINT Z (0 0 100).

Is this a bug or my mistake?

python 3.7.0, shapely 1.6.4

Comment: If you copy the `affine_transform` function from [https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/affinity.py](here), your code works as expected. However the function that is actually called is [`_speedups.affine_transform(geom, matrix)`](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/2df3a0fe62a290e0c564c3903f316ea8ab0c9a5b/shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx#L489). Which is harder to parse!

Answer (score 2):

I assume this was a bug. Seems to be working fine in Shapely 1.7.0:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.affinity import affine_transform

point1 = Point(0, 100, 200)

matrix = [1,0,0, 0,0,1, 0,1,0, 0,0,0]

point2 = affine_transform(point1, matrix)
print(f"From {np.array(point1.coords)} to {np.array(point2.coords)}")
# From [[  0. 100. 200.]] to [[  0. 200. 100.]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Shapely does not do anything on Z coordinates.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#geometric-objects:

> A third z coordinate value may be used when constructing instances,
>   but has no effect on geometric analysis. All operations are performed
>   in the x-y plane.

Comment: Yes, but Shapely affine transformation help 
 https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#affine-transformations say:  A collection of affine transform functions are in the shapely.affinity module, which return transformed geometries by either directly supplying coefficients to an affine transformation matrix, or by using a specific, named transform (rotate, scale, etc.). The functions can be used with all geometry types (except GeometryCollection), and 3D types are either preserved or supported by 3D affine transformations.

Comment: Oops, sorry! Then I cannot help any further. :)